# Why does $[X\in A]=[(X, Y)\in A\times \mathbb R]$

Tags: probability-theory

$X$ and $Y$ are both random variables, $X,Y:(\Omega,\mathcal A)\to\mathbb (R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R) )$, $A\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R) )$

On an intuitive level, this is perfectly clear. But I am unsure of the inner workings. Here's my understanding:

$$[X\in A]=\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega)\in A\}$$
$$[(X,Y) \in A\times \mathbb R]=\{(\omega_1,\omega_2)\in \Omega\times \Omega: (X,Y)(\omega_1,\omega_2)\in A \times \mathbb R\}$$

Now, one set is a set of *elements* of $\Omega$, the other a set of *ordered pairs*. **In what sense are these two sets equal?**

**edit**: I may have gotten an idea where I am wrong. Isn't it that these sets do **NOT** equal to each other, but the operations with them, i.e. their measure, does?

I am currently transforming my previous non-rigorous education in to a rigorous one by studying set/measure/probability theory, so the more rigor you bring into the answer, the better. I don't want to leave any cognitive gaps on the road from the axioms of set theory and rudimentary notions of mathematics to complicated concepts in probability.

Thank you.

Comment: So, your question basically is: "*In what sense are these two sets equal?*"

Comment: @Berci: true, an actual question on a Q&A site would probably be appropriate. Added, thanks.

Comment: Anyway, what we do have on the level of these sets is
$$[(X_1,X_2)\in A\times\Bbb R]=[X\in A]\times\Omega$$

Comment: I agree and understand, but I do not feel this addresses my problem completely. I've added an edit to the question, which might hopefully be steering my thinking into the right direction.

Comment: "the other a set of ordered pairs." - No it isn't. $[(X,Y)\in A\times \mathbb{R}]=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid (X(\omega),Y(\omega))\in A\times\mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: @Berci It appears that other answers are not consistent with your comment (see discussion under Augustin's answer), would you like to elaborate or change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$[(X,Y) \in A\times \mathbb R]=\{\omega\in\Omega,\, (X(\omega),Y(\omega))\in A\times\mathbb{R}\}$$

Comment: Thanks (to Stefan Hansen, too), that does make some sense to me, but then, say, what if $Y$ was from a different $\Omega'$? What would the set then look like?

Comment: If $Y$ was defined on another $\Omega$, it wouldn't a good idea tu use this notation. 

$[(X,Y) \in A\times \mathbb R]$ is just a simplified notation for $\{\omega\in\Omega,\, (X(\omega),Y(\omega))\in A\times\mathbb{R}\}$. You should use it only if it's not ambiguous.

Comment: What if we were interested in $[(X,Y)\in A\times B]$? Since you use the same $\omega$ for both $X$ and $Y$ at the same time, wouldn't that be a problem? Or is that again a case where this notation wouldn't work?

Comment: What's the problem? $[(X,Y)\in A\times B]=\{\omega\in\Omega,\, (X(\omega),Y(\omega))\in A\times B\}$

Comment: I suppose my fault was thinking that $[(X,Y)\in A\times B] = [X \in A]\times [Y \in B]$, but then was Berci (in the comments) wrong in saying that $[(X,Y)\in A\times\mathbb R] = [X\in A] \times \Omega$ ?

Comment: Yes, it should be a subset of $\Omega$.